# WPF Designer not finding culture on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, culture

I was doing a tutorial on WPFs but I can't edit anything on MainWindow.xaml because of an exception.

[image: Exception shown]

The error says:

> MissingSatelliteAssemblyException: The satellite assembly named
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.resources.dll,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5a3a" for fallback culture
>   "en" either could not be found or could not be loaded. This is
>   generally a setup problem. Please consider reinstalling or repairing
>   the application.

Comment: How is this asp.net?

Comment: What happened when you took the advice to either do a `repair` or `reinstall`?